# Error Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Hi I have this code in Node.Js, in this I realize a find query with mongoose

```
router.post('/query',function(req,res,next){
    if (req.body){
        var result=[];
        console.log(req.body.filters);
        Pollee.find(req.body.filters)
        .select('id age birthday user')
        .populate('user','email')
        .lean(true)
        .exec(function(err,pollees){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return next(err);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < pollees.length; i++){              
            var query =  test(pollees[i]._id);
            query.exec(function(err,inters){
                if(err)
                    return console.log(err);
                inters.forEach(function(inter){
                    pollees[i].interaction = inter; 
                });
            });
            }
            res.json(pollees);    
            };
        }) 
    }
});

function test(id){
   var promise = Interaction.find({pollee:id}).select('status other');
   return promise;
}
```

My problem here its in the Interaction.find when I try to pass the results of this query on pollees[i].interaction = inter; the console set me error

> Cannot set property pollees[i].interaction = inter; of undefined

Any idea?

The models I used

```
var interactionSchema = new Schema({
    pollee: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Pollee' },
    answers: { type: [ObjectId], ref: 'Answer', autopopulate: true },
    status: type: String
});

var PolleeSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    gender: String,
    user: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true }, 
    interactions: { type: [ObjectId], ref: 'Interaction', autopopulate: true }
});

var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    pollee: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pollee', autopopulate: true }
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the problem the following: in the `for` cycle of your code you're calling async method `query.exec()`. By the time it executes it's callback, for cycle has already finished and value of `i === pollees.length`. Thus `pollees[i]` is pointing to non-existent array element (undefined) and you get an error "cannot set property of undefined" when your trying to set it's property `interaction`.
One of the ways to fix this would be to use `.bind`:

```
query.exec(function(i, err,inters){ //i is among the params in your callback
    if(err)
        return console.log(err);
    inters.forEach(function(inter){
        pollees[i].interaction = inter; 
    });
}.bind(null, i)); //you're binding the variable 'i' to the callback
```

EDIT:

And in order for `res.json(pollees);` to work (which is a different problem) you should wrap all your callbacks in a `Promise`. It should probably look like something like this:

```
var queries = []; //an array of promises
for (var i = 0; i < pollees.length; i++){              
    queries.push(test(pollees[i]._id)); //add a promise to the array
}
//wait for all promises to resolve
Promise.all(queries).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(inter, index){
        pollees[index].interaction = inter; 
    });
    res.json(pollees); //return response
});
```

Comment: Works but pollees its returned without interaction field

Comment: sure, because you're returning the response before the callbacks get executed